# Spring Social Facebook email null

Tags: spring, facebook, spring-mvc, facebook-graph-api, spring-social

I try to integrate spring social facebook to my project (i already have managed to integrate google+ and twitter signin). The problem i have is with facebook provider which returns null for the most values. I use below code:

```
Connection<Facebook> fb_connection = (Connection<Facebook>) providerSignInUtils.getConnectionFromSession(request);   
fb_connection.getApi().userOperations().getUserProfile().getName();//i get the name
fb_connection.getApi().userOperations().getUserProfile().getId(); //i get the id
fb_connection.getApi().userOperations().getUserProfile().getEmail(); // email and all other values are always null
```

I tried many versions of spring social facebook right now i use 2.0.0.M1 which i think is the latest.
Below is the signin form i use:

```
<!-- FACEBOOK SIGNIN -->
<form name="fb_signin" id="fb_signin" action="<c:url value="/signin/facebook"/>" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="scope" value="email,public_profile,user_friends" />
    <button type="submit">Facebook</button>
</form>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4_changes, “declarative fields”. If the framework does not expose the actual API request it makes to you, then you will have to ask the creators to adapt their code accordingly.

Comment: Problem solved! I were using an older spring facebook version the current is 2.0.1.RELEASE.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue and solved it upgrading to the plugin version 2.0.2.RELEASE

```
<!-- Spring Social Facebook -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-social-facebook</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: thank you, I had same problem. Without your help I would still wasting my time.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had to send the "scope" field within the form where the sign in button is placed.

```
<form th:action="@{/connect/facebook}" method="POST">
<button type="submit">Sign in with Facebook</button>
<input type="hidden" name="scope" value="public_profile,email"/>
</form>
```